# Frobenius Norm Triangle Inequality

Tags: normed-spaces

How can I go about proving the triangle inequality holds for the Frobenius norm?

I worked through $\|A+B\|_F \le \|A\|_F + \|B\|_F$ and was not able to make it work =/.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the fact that it's a norm  from inner product :
$$\langle A,B \rangle = \text{Trace}(A^TB)$$
Then:
$$\|A+B\|^2=\|A\|^2+\|B\|^2+2\langle A,B\rangle$$
using Cauchy-Schwarz inequalitie we have  : $$\langle A,B\rangle  \leq \|A\| \|B\|$$
and this gives:
$$\|A+B\|^2 \leq  \|A\|^2+\|B\|^2+2 \|A\| \|B\|= (\|A\| + \|B\|)^2$$

Comment: It might be problematic using Cauchy-Schwartz, as usually you need to prove triangle-inequality to prove a function is indeed a norm, but CS requires you to know it's a norm (or an inner product for that case).

Answer (score 7):

It suffices to show $$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}+\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2}\geqslant\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i+y_i)^2}.$$Sqaure it, it's equivalent to show$$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2}\geqslant\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i,$$ which is the Cauchy-Schwartz Inequality.

It also works in $\mathbb{C}$ with slight modification.