# Show that the nuclear norm is a norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms, nuclear-norm

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. Define

$$\|A\| = \sum_{i=1}^{\min(n,m)} \sigma_i$$

where $\sigma_i$ are the singular values of $A$. How to show that $\|A\|$ is norm?

---

We want to verify the definition of norm.

Homogeneity $\|\alpha A\| = |\alpha| \times \|A\|$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

Triangular Inequality: $\|A+B\| \leq \|A\| + \|B\|$

Positive definiteness: if $\|A\|=0$, then $A=0$

Comment: Are you of your formula? Normally, $\;\|A\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{\min(n,m)} \sigma_i^2}$.

Comment: The main (only) difficulty concerns the triangle inequality. It was already demonstrated, for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/564873/621834

Comment: @Jospehin The norm $\sum_i \sigma_i$ is not called the "Frobenius norm", so it is not clear what you are asking. Please clarify whether you are asking about the Frobenius norm or about the norm with the formula that you give (usually called the "nuclear norm").

Comment: Homogeneity and positive definiteness are obvious. To prove the triangle inequality, since the appendment of zero rows or columns does not affect the nuclear norm, you may assume that $A$ is a square matrix. Then you may use the characterisation $\|A\|=\max|\operatorname{tr}(AU)|$ where the maximum is taken over all unitary matrices $U$.